# How can I make the container pop out inside the container using stack in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using stack in flutter, however I am having problem with the container at the top. I want to make the top container to overflow so I can see the whole container.

```
Stack(
                                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: 150,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        "assets/Untitled.png",
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Positioned(
                                      bottom: -50,
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 100,
                                        width: 100,
                                        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                        child: Image.network(data!['profile']),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
```

I have already tried using clipBehavior: Clip.none, inside the stack, but it seems that it does not do anything and the container is till not overflowed.

Comment: check parents widget of that Stack, such as another Container... and set ClipBehavior to Clip.none for them.

Comment: try changing the Padding with a Container, then set it's padding property and ClipBehavior

Comment: Can you give UI image?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(200),
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: -50,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `Container` within the `Positioned` will be out of the parent `Container`'s bounds on the left side by 50px. Make sure there are no parent widgets that are causing the Container to fit to the bounds of its children.